# Secret not fetched from current namespace, but from the default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have some deployments running in a custom namespace. They reference a secret `azure-files` to obtain the credentials to map a volume. This mapping is done like this:

```yaml
volumes:
- azureFile:
    secretName: azure-files
    shareName: myshare
  name: azure
```

When I apply the YAML, then the pods try to spin up, but fail. When I describe the pod I see the following error:

```
Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
----     ------       ----               ----               -------
Normal   Scheduled    26s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned development-l56t08/develop-is4-58b4d966b4-948dw to aks-agentpool-41062645-vmss000002
Warning  FailedMount  10s (x6 over 26s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "azure" : Couldn't get secret default/azure-files
```

For some reason Kubernetes attempts to fetch the secret from the default namespace instead of my own namespace. When I add the secret to the default namespace, everything works. Does anyone know how to solve this? I was under the impression that you couldn't even reference secrets in other namespaces.

The secret does exist in my namespace and other secrets seem to work fine...

Comment: I have made some research and it seems that problem is still unsolved - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70044 Also did you take a look https://serverfault.com/questions/1024219/cannot-mount-cifs-storage-on-k8s-cluster ?

Comment: I got this error when upgrading my cluster to Kubernetes 1.19. I thought it failed during the recreate of the pod, but it's an issue in Azure AKS: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/99061

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in AKS code.

> Whatever the CSI driver mechanism does with secrets must remain backwards compatible with and adapt to the in-tree implementations,  not the other way around.
>
> Please revert  [#97417](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/97417)  and pick to 1.18-1.20 to restore compatibility to the 1.18-1.20 releases.  This needs to happen before 1.18 leaves maintenance
> (https://github.com/kubernetes/sig-release/blob/master/releases/patch-releases.md#118)
>
> the csi translation library change in
> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/97877/files#r596900593
> may need adjustment as well

For track the bug check: [azurefile-aks](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/99061).